# Why/When to add an inputMismatchException?

Tags: java, exception

This is a code sample. If I was to enter numerator: 5 and Denominator: 0

I get an exception like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at ExceptionHandling.DivideByZeroExceptions.quotient(DivideByZeroExceptions.java:10)
at ExceptionHandling.DivideByZeroExceptions.main(DivideByZeroExceptions.java:22)
```

I know I have to include ( throws Arithmetic Exception )
But, How would I know that I need to use a inputMismatchException?

```
 // Try DivideByZeroExceptions

  public class DivideByZeroExceptions {

public static int quotient(int numerator, int denominator) {
    return numerator / denominator;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer numerator: ");
    int numerator = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter an integer denominator: ");
    int denominator = input.nextInt();

    int result = quotient(numerator, denominator);
    System.out.printf("\nResult: %d / %d = %d\n", numerator, denominator,
            result);

}
```

}

Comment: In this case I wouldn't throw an exception, I would check the input and give the user a friendly error message and a chance to try again. Exceptions are not user friendly.

Comment: So, When should I use an exception? Give me an example case where I should be better using an exception.

Comment: You should throw an Exception when you expect it to be caught by software calling your method or library.

Comment: Alright, will keep it mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your asking about inputMismatchException, but this is what you should do:

```
public static int quotient(int numerator, int denominator) {
    if(denominator == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot divide by 0!");
    return numerator / denominator;
}
```

`IllegalArgumentException` extends `RuntimeException`, not just `Exception`. As such, it will simply stop execution of the thread after it occurs, so it doesn't need to be caught/thrown (of course you can still catch it outside the method in order to prevent the Thread from stopping).

Comment: @RonyJohn Yup :) Mark it as correct too please (seems like that's what you wanted)

Answer (score 2):

Both `ArithmeticException` and `InputMismatchException` are unchecked exceptions (sub-types of `RuntimeException`). This means that you are not required to catch or throw them, but however, you need to handle the cases that cause them.

For instance, in order to avoid the `DivideByZeroException` (`ArithmeticException`) your program must check if the denominator is not zero. If it is, don't do the division.

Comment: Hmm, Interesting!! College Textbooks confuse me -__-. So, what are some scenario's where I am expected to use an exception?

Comment: Checked exceptions (that are not subclasses of RuntimeException) always need to be caught. Your code (API) can throw existing or custom (defined by you) exceptions in unexpected situations.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare exceptions derived from `RuntimeExceptions` in your throws clause (v.g., `NullPointerException`). That's why the compiler does not tell you that you must declare it (for other Exceptions, you will get a compiler error/the IDE will signal a mistake in the method declaration).

Of course, if one of the methods you are calling might throw it, you can catch it as any other exception.

Check [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)